# Call to undefined method Learning\Test\Model\Resource\Test\Collection::getCollection() in Magento 2

Tags: adminhtml, magento2-dev-beta

I have created Magento 2 Test Module which is connected to DB, it is throwing error while fetching collection. Any Idea on this.

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method
>   Learning\Test\Model\Resource\Test\Collection::create() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\magento-2\app\code\Learning\Test\Block\Adminhtml\Test\Grid.php
>   on line 40

here i'm giving Model and Block(Container) Code.

my code is:

**app\code\Magento\Learning\Test\Model\Test.php**

```
<?php

namespace Learning\Test\Model;

class Test extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel
{

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Learning\Test\Model\Resource\Test $resource,
        \Learning\Test\Model\Resource\Test\Collection $resourceCollection
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $registry,
            $resource,
            $resourceCollection
        );
    }

}

?>
```

**app\code\Learning\Test\Model\Resource\Test.php**

```
<?php

namespace Learning\Test\Model\Resource;

class Test extends \Magento\Framework\Model\Resource\Db\AbstractDb
{

    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('test', 'id');
    }

}

?>
```

**app\code\Learning\Test\Model\Resource\Test\Collection.php**

```
<?php

namespace Learning\Test\Model\Resource\Test;

class Collection extends \Magento\Framework\Model\Resource\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Learning\Test\Model\Test', 'Learning\Test\Model\Resource\Test');
    }

}

?>
```

**app\code\Learning\Test\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index.php**

```
<?php

namespace Learning\Test\Controller\Adminhtml\Test;

class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        //$this->_title->add(__('Manage Banners'));

        if ($this->getRequest()->getQuery('ajax')) {
            $this->_forward('grid');
            return;
        }
        $this->_view->loadLayout();

        /**
         * Set active menu item
         */
        $this->_setActiveMenu('test');

        /**
         * Add breadcrumb item
         */
        $this->_addBreadcrumb(__('Records'), __('Records'));
        $this->_addBreadcrumb(__('Manage Records'), __('Manage Records'));

        $this->_view->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

**app\code\Learning\Test\Block\Adminhtml\Test\Test.php**

```
<?php
namespace Learning\Test\Block\Adminhtml;

use \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Container;

class Test extends Container
{

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {

        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_test';
        $this->_blockGroup = 'Learning_Test';
        $this->_headerText = __('Custom Module');
        $this->_addButtonLabel = __('Add New Record');
        parent::_construct();
    }

}
```

**app\code\Learning\Test\Block\Adminhtml\Test\Grid.php**

```
<?php

namespace Learning\Test\Block\Adminhtml\Test;

class Grid extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended
{

    protected $_bannerFactory;

    protected $_banner;


   public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Backend\Helper\Data $backendHelper,
        \Learning\Test\Model\Resource\Test\Collection $bannerFactory,
        \Learning\Test\Model\Test $banner,
        array $data = array()
    ) {
        $this->_bannerFactory = $bannerFactory;
        $this->_banner = $banner;
        parent::__construct($context, $backendHelper, $data);
    }

    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setId('testGrid');
        $this->setDefaultSort('id');
        $this->setDefaultDir('DESC');
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
        $this->setUseAjax(true);
    }

    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {   

        //$collection = $this->_bannerFactory->getCollection();

        $collection = $this->_bannerFactory->create()->getCollection();

        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/Collection.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $logger->info($collection);


        /*
         * $collection = array();
         *
        $adapter = $this->_banner->_getReadAdapter();
        $select = $adapter->select()->from($this->_banner->getTable('test'), '*');
        $allRows = $adapter->fetchAll($select);
        foreach($allRows as $key => $value){
            $data = new \Magento\Framework\Object(array('key' => $key, 'value' => $value));
            $collection->addItem($data);
        }

        */

        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $this->addColumn(
            'id',
            array(
                'header' => __('ID'),
                'type' => 'number',
                'index' => 'id'
               /* 'header_css_class' => 'col-id',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-id'*/
            )
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'firstname',
            array(
                'header' => __('First Name'),
                'index' => 'firstname',
                'class' => 'xxx'
            )
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'lastname',
            array(
                'header' => __('Last Name'),
                'index' => 'lastname',
                'class' => 'xxx'
            )
        );

        $this->addColumn(
            'edit',
            array(
                'header' => __('Edit'),
                'type' => 'action',
                'getter' => 'getId',
                'actions' => array(
                    array(
                        'caption' => __('Edit'),
                        'url' => array(
                            'base' => '*/*/edit',
                            'params' => array('store' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('store'))
                        ),
                        'field' => 'id'
                    )
                ),
                'filter' => false,
                'sortable' => false,
                'index' => 'stores'
                /*'header_css_class' => 'col-action',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-action'*/
            )
        );
        $block = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('grid.bottom.links');
        if ($block) {
            $this->setChild('grid.bottom.links', $block);
        }

        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }

    /**
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _prepareMassaction()
    {
        $this->setMassactionIdField('entity_id');
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->setFormFieldName('test');

        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem(
            'delete',
            array(
                'label' => __('Delete'),
                'url' => $this->getUrl('testadmin/*/massDelete'),
                'confirm' => __('Are you sure?')
            )
        );

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getGridUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('test/*/grid', array('_current' => true));
    }
    public function getRowUrl($row)
    {
        return $this->getUrl(
            'test/*/edit',
            array('store' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('store'), 'id' => $row->getId())
        );
    }
}
```

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method
>   Learning\Test\Model\Resource\Test\Collection::create() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\magento-2\app\code\Learning\Test\Block\Adminhtml\Test\Grid.php
>   on line 40

Any help on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the file `app\code\Learning\Test\Block\Adminhtml\Test\Grid.php` this constructor parameter

```
\Learning\Test\Model\Resource\Test\Collection $bannerFactory,
```

should be

```
\Learning\Test\Model\Resource\Test\CollectionFactory $bannerFactory,
```

then later in the `_prepareCollection` method replace

```
$collection = $this->_bannerFactory->create()->getCollection();
```

with

```
$collection = $this->_bannerFactory->create();
```

Note:
Don't panic if your IDE tells you that the class `Learning\Test\Model\Resource\Test\CollectionFactory` does not exist. It will be auto-generated at runtime.

Comment: Yes, Now working fine. Thank You. Yes IDE tells `CollectionFactory` and `create()` method is does not exist, but it's working @ run time.